# Constructor cannot be applied to given types - newb needing clarification

Tags: java, serialization

I have been reading various articles about serialisation, I am a newb to Java, I have searched for my errors, but despite reading a lot, I fail to understand why my program won't compile and what I need to change. I've read that my problem is the arguments in my constructor, but nothing seems to fix it. I'm not looking for someone to do it for me, just a pointer in the right direction. I have these classes in seperate files and have tried with them in a package and out of a package.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Employee implements Serializable
{
   public String firstName;
   public String lastName;
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 5462223600l;
}
```

Employee.java has it's own file and it compiles on it's own

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class SerializaitonClass {        // held in SerializaitonClass.java

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp.firstName = "Vivekanand";
        emp.lastName = "Gautam";

        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new     FileOutputStream("./employee.txt");
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            out.writeObject(emp);
            out.close();
            fileOut.close();
            System.out.printf("Serialized data is saved in ./employee.txt file");
        } catch (IOException i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Serialisation.java does not compile, specific errors are: `Constructor Employee in Class Employee cannot be applied to given types`. The compiler also doesn't recognise `emp.firstName` and `emp.lastName`

Finally, can anyone suggest a very simple guide to serialization, I think I am close to understanding everything, but I need something which is written in "Newb" terms.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. It compiles fine for me. Please add more informations about how you are compiling those files.

Comment: Both snippets compile fine in my IDE -- perhaps you haven't actually compiled `Employee.java`, which is why you're seeing errors while compiling `SerializaitonClass.java`.

Comment: Ok, I am not using an IDE, I am using notepad and dos. I'll use Netbeans eventually. Employee.java compiles fine, so I have a .class file for Employee. The errors occur when I compile SerializaitonClass.java , errors are listed earlier in this post. My JRE is version 1.8.0_40 and my environment variables are not an issue, other programs compile fine. It's early days in coding, so I would prefer not declare as a package just yet. Any pointers in the right direction would be great :)

Comment: Having looked into this further, I am convinced this is an issue with my environment, not my code. But other, more simple, programs compile and execute. My Path environment variable is as follows:  C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin   where as my classpath is just C:\;            Iam compiling from the following directory   C:\Test\Tutorialspoint\

Comment: Does anyone know whether this a compiler version issue? I am utterly convinced it is my environment, but other programs compile and I cannot find any articles regarding serialization issues with compilers. Thanks :)

Comment: I downloaded Netbeans and I presume a different JDK, and it works! I can only conclude that this is a compiler version issue. I updated the JRE previously, and that didn't make any difference.